# Widget size shows up as 3x1 on portrait and 4x1 on landscape

Tags: android, android-widget, screen-size, nexus-7

I am developing an android homescreen widget with size 250dp x 40dp for API versions above 14.

By testing this widget on my Nexus 7, I found out that when the tablet is placed in a portrait mode, the widget gets a 3x1 size but when switched on landscape it gets a 4x1 size.

See the images below:

**Portrait:**
[image]

**Landscape:**
[image]
Testing it on a nexus 10 gives 3x1 for both orientations.

What can I do to have the same size on all orientations and devices ?